# how to write a function like Mma's NestList in Python

Tags: python, list, function, iterator

For example :
NestList(f,x,3) ---->  [x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x)))]

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write it as a generator:

```
def nestList(f,x,c):
    for i in range(c):
        yield x
        x = f(x)
    yield x

import math
print(list(nestList(math.cos, 1.0, 10)))
```

Or if you want the results as a list, you can append in a loop:

```
def nestList(f,x,c):
    result = [x]
    for i in range(c):
        x = f(x)
        result.append(x)
    return result

import math
print(nestList(math.cos, 1.0, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like a  recursion version, is it difficult?

Comment: @chyanog: No it's not difficult. But why do you want a recursive version? It would be less efficient and overflow the stack for large values of the third parameter.

Comment: Sure, sometimes I just feel it's neat。

Comment: @chyanog: For a recursive version consider that `nestList(f,x,c)` is the same as `[x] + nestList(f,f(x),c-1)`.

Comment: @MarkByers What would you say is the most efficient way to do this if you are interested only in the final value of the nested list?

Answer (score 1):

```
def nest_list(f, x, i):
        if i == 0:
            return [x]
        return [x] + nest_list(f, f(x), i-1)


def nest_list(f, x, n):
    return [reduce(lambda x,y: f(x), range(i), x) for i in range(n+1)]
```

I found another way did it!

Comment: In Python 3.3, you can also write this as `list(accumulate(repeat(x, n), lambda x,y: f(x)))`, using `accumulate` and `repeat` from the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `functional` module. It has a function called `scanl`, which yields each stage of a reduction. You can then reduce a list of instances of `f`.

Comment: It works, and I found a function called iterate. `it=functional.iterate(lambda x: 2*x-1,2)  print [it.next() for i in range(11)]`

Comment: @chyanog Glad to be of assistance. Don't forget to accept an answer.

Comment: @chyanog Note however, that because what you have is an iterator, you can iterate it directly - you don't need to use a list comprehension. Also, check out the utilities in `itertools` to do things like taking a slice from an iterator (`itertools.islice`).

Comment: Thansks. That's useful for me.